# Can I define a maxima function f(x) which assigns to the argument x

Tags: function, maxima

Sorry for the basic question, but it's quite hard to find too much discussion on Maxima specifics.

I'm trying to learn some Maxima and wanted to use something like

```
x:2
x+=2
```

which as far as I can tell doesn't exist in Maxima. Then I discovered that I can define my own operators as infix operators, so I tried doing

```
infix("+=");
"+=" (a,b):= a:(a+b);
```

However this doesn't work, as if I first set `x:1` then try calling `x+=2`, the function returns 3, but if I check the value of x I see it hasn't changed.

Is there a way to achieve what I was trying to do in Maxima? Could anyone explain why the definition I gave fails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that there is too much and too little evaluation -- the `+=` function doesn't see the symbol `x` so it doesn't know to what variable to assign the result, and the left-hand side of an assignment isn't evaluated, so `+=` thinks it is assigning to `a`, not `x`.

Here's one way to get the right amount of evaluation. `::=` defines a macro, which is just a function which quotes its arguments, and for which the return value is evaluated again. `buildq` is a substitution function which quotes the expression into which you are substituting. So the combination of `::=` and `buildq` here is to construct the `x: x + 2` expression and then evaluate it.

```
(%i1) infix ("+=") $
(%i2) "+="(a, b) ::= buildq ([a, b], a: a + b) $
(%i3) x: 100 $
(%i4) macroexpand (x += 1);
(%o4)                       x : x + 1
(%i5) x += 1;
(%o5)                          101
(%i6) x;
(%o6)                          101
(%i7) x += 1;
(%o7)                          102
(%i8) x;
(%o8)                          102
```

So it is certainly possible to do so, if you want to do that. But may I suggest maybe you don't need it? Modifying a variable makes it harder to keep track, mentally, what is going on. A programming policy such as one-time assignment can make it easier for the programmer to understand the program. This is part of a general approach called functional programming; perhaps you can take a look at that. Maxima has various features which make it possible to use functional programming, although you are not required to use them.

Comment: Thank you, that's a really helpful explanation.

Comment: I agree I don't need the function, but once I'd realised it didn't exist, trying to write it seemed like a good way of understanding how to write functions in Maxima.

I actually wanted it just as a shorthand inside a loop, for example `block([count:0], for i:0 thru 4 do count+=1, count);`. In your opinion, is there a better way that should be written?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with modifying a variable in a loop, but it makes it harder (for anyone reading the code, including the original author) to understand what's going on, and also it opens the door for problems if the loop doesn't get fully executed. What if the loop doesn't get all the way through all the iterations? Then there will be some kind of incomplete state, which, again, has to be understood.

Comment: A conceptually simpler approach is to state the operation as something to be carried out all in one shot. E.g. `sum(1, k, 1, 4)` yields the same result as the for-loop. From the point of view of someone reading the code, `sum` is a single operation. Other common examples include representing the summation of the product of two lists as `a . b` (with `listarith = true`, which see) instead of `block([foo: 0], for i thru length(a) do foo: foo + a[i]*b[i], foo)` and creating a list via `makelist` or `map` or `sublist` instead of incrementally via `for`.

Comment: Sometimes there isn't any obvious way to do things in a functional way. That's OK, the important point is to just try to make things as clear as possible.